# g++ ld shared library error with code::blocks

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, shared-libraries

There are similar topics, but I haven't managed to find my answer in them.

I am building a test console application using the code::blocks IDE. It needs to load a DVB shared library called libhdhomerun.so (from Silicon Dust) for the HD Homerun DVB tuners. The HDHR tuner library has being installed using ./configure, ..., sudo make install, ldconfig etc and it all works with their utilities (built at the same time). So - the library is there and OK.

The library installed itself into /usr/local/lib. There is actually no symlink to it as there is with other shared libraries, but then it doesn't have any version information on the end either.

When I build the code (having explicitly included /usr/local/lib/libhdhomerun.so), the ld stage fails with

```
"cannot find -lhdhomerun.so"
```

I have tried every combination of including (/usr/local/lib/) libhdhomerun.so, hdhomerun.so, libhdhomerun, hdhomerun, creating a symlink to it etc. Nothing makes any difference.

The bizarre thing is that I have udev, mysql and libdvbv5 shared libraries included in exactly the same way, and they are fine. The only one that will not link is hdhomerun.

If I run a manual verbose link step from the command line "ld -lhdhomerun.so --verbose", it does fail - because it is trying to find libhdhomerun.so.so.

Any suggestions gratefully received - but I do need to keep using code::blocks.

Comment: As you've already discovered the `-l` directive takes the library name without `lib` and without extension, e.g. `-lhdhomerun`.
It is weird that it has no so-version, which often indicates a plugin rather than a "normal" library, but in a "normal" library location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To link the library properly, you need to have library path defined in your environment, and use proper library name with -l flag. Library path is defined in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. For `-l` flag to `g++`, library extension should not be provided - as you already observed, so in your case it should be like this:

```
-lhdhomerun
```

Comment: Thanks. After a lot of experimentation with the above, it just started working - with the original settings. Confused.